# Windows PowerShell - Delete Files Older than X Days

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am currently new at PowerShell and I have created a script based on gathered information on the net that will perform a Delete Operation for found files within a folder that have their LastWriteTime less than 1 day.

Currently the script is as follows:

```
$timeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) 
$oldBackups = Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Recurse -Force -Filter "backup_cap_*" |
                Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit}

foreach($backup in $oldBackups)
{
    Remove-Item $dest\$backup -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}
```

As far as I know the `-WhatIf` command will output to the console what the command "should" do in real-life scenarios. The problem is that `-WhatIf` does not output anything and even if I remove it the files are not getting deleted as expected.

The server is Windows 2012 R2 and the command is being runned within PowerShell ISE V3.

When the command will work it will be "translated" into a task that will run each night after another task has finished backing up some stuff.

Comment: 2) If you want to delete files, why are you only including folders with `$PSIsContainer` ? 3) If that's your script, where is $dest coming from? If it's not defined, gci will read the current working directory without error. 4) Have you confirmed that `$oldBackups` has anything in it? 5) Does `Remove-Item` throw any exceptions about files not existing?

Comment: $dest is declared above in an outer scope. It's the Working Directory of the script. The backups are created there. And no, no exceptions are thrown. Regarding the $PSIsContainer, you are right. We have decided that backups will not be in folder, they will be directly in the Working Directory, so basically the backups will be under the pattern backup_cap_dateOfWrite that is outputted by the mysqldump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it in the pipe

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

This worked for me. So you don't have to ttake care of the right path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

other solution

```
$timeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) 
Get-ChildItem C:\temp2 -Directory | where LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit  | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

The original issue was `$dest\$backup` would assume that each file was in the root folder. But by using the `fullname` property on `$backup`, you don't need to statically define the directory.

One other note is that Remove-Item takes arrays of strings, so you also could get rid of the `foreach`

Here's the fix to your script, without using the pipeline. Note that since I used the `where` method this requires at least version 4

```
$timeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) 
$Backups = Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Directory -Recurse -Force -Filter "backup_cap_*"
$oldBackups = $backups.where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit}
Remove-Item $oldBackups.fullname -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```