# Powershell - Delete files older then X days

Tags: powershell

I have the below script that is meant to delete files older then X days but it wont do anything. I have it output a message to a TXT file to say if its successfull or not and still no success. any ideas?

```html
$Path = "H:\Test\Test2"
$Days = "-0"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$Extension = "*."
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Days)
$DeleteHistoryFile = "H:\Test\TestLogDeleteHistory.txt"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Include $extension | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete}

if ($Files -ne $null) 
    {
        foreach ($File in $Files) {
            $Message = "$file has been deleted based on a $Days day rentention policy."
            $Message | Out-File $DeleteHistoryFile -Append
            Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
            }             
        }
    else
    {
    $message_no_files = "$DatetoDelete`: There are no files older than $Days days, no files were be deleted"
    $message_no_files | Out-File $DeleteHistoryFile -Append
    }
```

the difference in my script is that i need it to output if its successful or not.

plus

Can someone please explain how I can run this from a local machine to a remote server. What do i need to think about when i set it up? or is it easier to run it straight on that box?

Comment: `$Days = "-0"` is the culprit here. Since you are using a double quote, `$Days` becomes a string. See `$Days.GetType()`. Change that to `$Days = -0`. Even better. Since you are not actually subtracting any number of days your `$DatetoDelete` can be equal to  `$CurrentDate`.

Comment: @rohan groombridge - the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters are ... unreliable when you do NOT also use `-Recurse`. on my win7ps5.1 system your `$Files` variable never has anything in it. [*grin*] try changing the `-Include` to -Filter` - it works faster and you have only the one extension, so it is likely the better way to go. ///// also, your `'*.'` extension will get files AND directories. so if you want no-extension files, i recommend you use the `-File` parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows PowerShell - Delete Files Older than X Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299527/windows-powershell-delete-files-older-than-x-days)